# WSS3.0 Workflow not attaching itself to items to be started

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, wss-3.0, wss

I have a sharepoint (WSS 3.0) site with several workflows on it.  The problem I have got is that it seems all the workflows have unattached themselves from the list items.  For example when I go to start a workflow manually against a list item (or document/form in a document/forms library) the workflows are not available to be selected to be started.  All workflows have the option to be started manually and automatically and the automatic starting of workflows (either when an item is changed or an item is created) is not happening either.

If i go into SharePoint designer and re-save the workflow it then does show but with a number 1 in brackets after the name, as though it is some kind of copy of the original workflow (i.e. if my workflow is called 'SendEmailWorkflow' in SharePoint Designer, when i open the workflow up and then click finish,  it saves fine but appears in sharepoint as 'SendEmailWorkflow (1)'.

Can anyone point me in the direction of what is going wrong here and help me get my workflows back so they run again?

Cheers

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: Hi Deepu, Yes and no is the answer.  Please see the forum thread I have got here on MSDN where I got a lot of useful responses: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointworkflow/thread/3ea29917-b0f6-4f86-91e4-714e8644aeda/